# How to Make my asterisk server to make Outbound Calls and Recieve Inbound

Tags: linux, sip, asterisk

I have an asterisk Soft PBX running on my Ubuntu Machine and i managed to do extensions calls from one softphone to another by doing required configurations in the `Sip.Conf` as well as `extension.conf`.I can dial as well as receive calls.Now my next target is to make this working for the real Outbound and Inbound calls.I will tell you i am a novice asterisk player who is trying to learn the things to play with.So my questions regarding this are:

**Do i need some hardware to make the required things happen, if yes,Please specify.**
**What are the nature of the `Dialplans` to execute the calls successfully.**

**What are the things we need to get from the Telephone Service Provider End.**

Also ,i will share that i am residing in `INDIA`.
Please guys help me.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you not need any hardware.

You need SIP trunk/voip provider.

Comment: Sir thanks for your answer,i want to make clear one more thing that, is PRI line call allowed in Asterisk.If yes how to do it?

Comment: For sip,iax2 you not need hardware. For PSTN you need fxo card. For PRI you need t1/e1 card.

Comment: Sir i have digital PRI card with me.Now will you please give me one example of the dialplan by which i may be able to do outgoing and incoming call..